# Unable to load custom PHP extension in PHP 5.3.5

Tags: php, windows, php-extension

I'm attempting to load a custom PHP extension on a Windows XP/IIS 5.1 development machine but I'm failing miserably.

I have...

- placed the PHP extension (*php_fortranwrapper.dll*) in the "ext" subfolder of my PHP 5.3.5 installation
- been editing the correct *php.ini* file (i.e. the one corresponding to the "Loaded Configuration File" entry listed in the phpinfo() output)
- set `extension_dir` in *php.ini* to point to the aforementioned "ext" subfolder
- added an `extension=php_fortranwrapper.dll` entry in *php.ini* to load the PHP extension
- restarted IIS (via `iisreset`)

On running a `phpinfo()` script, it tries to load the page until FastCGI times out with the following error:
*The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout*

If I rename the PHP extension to say php_fortranwrapper1.dll, I logically see the following error:
*PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:...\php-5.3.5\ext\php_fortranwrapper.dll' - The specified module could not be found.*

For information, I generated the PHP extension using PHP 5.3.5 and PHP4Delphi, a tool which compiles a PHP extension from Delphi source code. My Delphi code loads a Fortran DLL and passes an integer to a function in that Fortran DLL and expects an integer result back.

Comment: You sure, it's not a `zend_extension` you wanted to add?

Comment: I don't think so. The _php.ini_ file contains a section called "Dynamic Extensions" which is where all the `extension=php_xxx.dll` (e.g. `extension=php_mysql.dll`) statements reside for loading extensions automatically. Most of the tutorials I've read on building custom PHP extensions advise adding another line to this section to have a custom extension loaded automatically.

Comment: Having researched a little more (see <a href="http://web.archive.org/web/20080703225558rn_1/archive.devnewz.com/2002/0909.html">this archived site</a>), it appears that zend_extensions extend the Zend Engine itself and can alter how PHP behaves. All I want to do is add functionality to PHP.

Comment: Try attaching a debugger to see what's going on.

Comment: I've attached Xdebug and have used the XDebugClient program in an attempt to debug this issue. Annoyingly though, Xdebug never connects to the XDebugClient whilst the php_fortranwrapper.dll is included in the extensions list of php.ini - XDebugClient simply displays a "Waiting for xdebug to connect" status. <i>Note: I've verified that Xdebug talks to XDebugClient ordinarily by removing the extension entry for php_fortranwrapper.dll.</i> Does anyone have any ideas for a way forward?

Answer (score 2):

Have you made any of your own custom PHP external extensions before?

Can you post some of your Delphi code so people can peer into what the inner workings are?

Here is an example by Igal Raizman using C++ that may have some usable ideas on how to test:
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Developing-Custom-PHP-Extensions-Part-1/

If you haven't had any success before, maybe this idea would be a start?

Comment: Apologies for the belated reply. Many thanks for the link and for your comments. I'm afraid this is my first attempt at making my own custom PHP external extension. Since January, I've actually had more success interfacing PHP with a Fortran DLL using two alternative techniques: (1) a COM server written in Delphi, and (2) a console application written in Delphi called using PHP's exec command.